# Proportional hazards assumption and time-dependent covariates

Tags: cox-model, time-varying-covariate, proportional-hazards

Is there a way to check that the proportional hazards assumption is correct for a Cox model with time-varying covariates ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If we add time-dependent covariates or interactions with time to the Cox
>   proportional hazards model, then it is not a “proportional hazards” model
>   any longer.

See this presentation: http://ms.uky.edu/~mai/sta635/Cox%20model.pdf

or this lecture notes: http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~rxu/math284/slect7.pdf

But this is a widely known feature.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Serpico is true for time-dependent coefficients but not if the model uses time-dependant covariates. If this was the case, I don't know the correct answer.

Comment: This is a confusing answer.

Comment: _Time-dependent covariates_ are measured values that change along the study. _Time-dependents coefficients_ imply that some $\beta$ is not constant across time. Philosophically speaking, there's not much difference - since I guess there's always a way to convert between products $\beta(t) x $ and $ \beta x(t)$, if we can choose any shape of time-dependency.

Comment: @juod Your comment would therefore indicate that we must not verify the proportional hazards assumption with a model with time-dependent covariates. However, the answer for this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246488/does-the-proportional-hazards-assumption-still-matter-if-the-covariate-is-time-d appears to indicate otherwise

Comment: @Emmanuel.W I agree with you that such a model still assumes proportional hazards given same covariate levels. I was referring to the discrepancy between your answer and Serpico's references - they say that the term $\beta x t$ has a time-dependent covariate, while I'd say it's the coefficient that is time-dependent there.

Answer (score 2):

As Serpico suggests, the Cox model with time-dependent covariates is no longer a proportional hazards model. Here is a quote from David Collett's book, *Modelling Survival Data in Medical Research* (2nd ed., 2003, p. 253), that may provide some further clarification:

> It is important to note that in the model given in equation $h_i(t) = \exp \left\{ \sum_{j=1}^p \beta_j x_{ji}(t) \right\} h_o(t)$, the values of the variables $x_{ji}(t)$ depend on the time $t$, and so the relative hazard $h_i(t)/h_0(t)$ is also time-dependent. This means that the hazard of death at time $t$ is no longer proportional to the baseline hazard, and the model is no longer a proportional hazards model.